# Does Keras work with input data including None value?

Tags: python, keras

I'm working on DQN with Keras.
Input data array from learning environment includes some `None` values.
Can Keras models (Dense, Convolution2D for example) learn such data directly?
Or should I process the data in advance?

Any help, suggestion, advice will be appreciated. I'm new to Keras...

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its always better if you do some preprocessing on the data before running any model( like treating outliers and missing values).

This link will give you some ideas on how to use Keras for dqn

[Keras-rl Library](https://github.com/matthiasplappert/keras-rl)